# MPAndroidChart - Remove Top and Bottom Spaces

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

I am using [MPAndroidChart](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart) library.

I implement a PieChart in my application. Everything works fine, but there is a blank space at the top and at the end of the Chart.
I need to remove this space to properly visualize my activity layout

My question is:

- Is possible to remove them programmatically?

P.D. In my layout, there is non marginTop or marginBottom.

Layout xml:

```
<com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.PieChart
   android:id="@+id/pieChart"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_below="@id/_home_consumed" >
</com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.PieChart>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you tried calling `setOffsets(float left, float top, float right, float bottom)` on the `Chart`?

```
// add data...
chart.setData(...);

// define new offsets
chart.setOffsets(0, 0, 0, 0);

// update transformation matrix
chart.getTransformer().prepareMatrixValuePx(chart);
chart.getTransformer().prepareMatrixOffset(chart);

chart.getContentRect().set(0, 0, chart.getWidth(), chart.getHeight());

// redraw
chart.invalidate();
```

This should programamtically eliminate all offsets. Since the chart automatically adjusts it's offsets when calling the `setData(...)` method, in order to keep the offsets, this method needs to be called everytime a new data object is set for the chart.

I also know this is very complicated, I will simplify the process in the future.

Comment: At this time (2016) the PieChart doesn't have the `setOffset` method, I have tried with `setMinOffset` method, but the blank space still is here, any help?

Comment: @RosendoRopher, I know it's an workaround, but try using setExtraOffsets with negative values. It worked for me.

Answer (score 4):

Try this...

```
pieChart.setExtraOffsets(-10,-10,-10,-10);
```

Comment: Note that you may also need to call `chart.setMinOffset()` if the resulting offset size would be lower than the default minimum of 15.

Answer (score 2):

The pie chart does not only have a default offset of 10, but it also adds additional space to let you highlight the *selected* entry ([see this comment on GitHub](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/issues/1092#issuecomment-146927254). To remove all padding you need to remove the space for the selected entry, too:

```java
pieChart.setExtraOffsets(0, 0, 0, 0);

PieDataSet dataSet = new PieDataSet([..]);
dataSet.setSelectionShift(0f);
```

Answer (score 1):

minOffset is 15f by default,

so set the minOffset to zero (or a lower than default)
then call,

`setExtraOffsets(10f,0f,10f,0f)` [with whatever the values].

make sure you invalidate the changes by using

kotlin:

```
post {
    invalidate()
 }
```

Java:

```
post(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        chartView.invalidate();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

[Half Pie Chart Image using MPCHART](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qpDSV.png)

You can set offset in negative value like the below:-       **transactionTrendPieChart.setExtraOffsets(0,-100,0,-150);**

Comment: I have exactly the same problem you describe in your screenshot. 
But `extraOffset` behaves weirdly. It seems buggy. How do you find the offsets?

Answer (score 0):

[Andrew Briggs](https://stackoverflow.com/users/775046/andrew-briggs)'s `chart.setMinOffset(0);` answer worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

For an AndroidView on jetpack Compose the "chart.minOffset = 0f" it worked for me